# mysql_* function and cute little kitty

Tags: discussion

Mysql_* functions are deprecated and completely removed from php7. mysqli_* functions or PDO instead should be used.

> Everytime someone uses deprecated mysql_* functions a cute little
>   kitty dies somewhere in the world

I have seen this sentence for quite a few times. But, how is this related with cute little kitty. Is there something in it. or just a warning? or like little bobby table.

Comment: It's hyperbole...it's a way of saying that it shouldn't be done or something bad happens....or just expressing disappointment that users aren't using current expressions, terms & functions.

Comment: It's like everytime is I see HTML newbies using `<center>` a little piece of my souls dies.

Comment: As a doge lover, I would like to see everyone use those functions ;)

Comment: It is a play off of [a well-known meme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Every_time_you_masturbate..._God_kills_a_kitten). See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116286/what-does-it-mean-when-x-does-y-god-kills-z

Comment: what's wrong with <center>?@Paulie_D

Comment: [This](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/R-LL4TWvQOc/hqdefault.jpg) is the kitten that will get killed if you personally use the mysql functions again :)

Comment: @SanzeebAryal ...because `<center>` is **also** deprecated and obsolete...as another part of my soul vanishes into the aether.

Comment: PHP developers regularly murder kittens.  They only blame it on Mysql_* use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is pretty much a variation of the "every time bla, a kitten dies" meme. If you are not familiar with memes at this point in time, I have respect for you.

https://memegenerator.net/God-Kills-A-Kitten

So rest assured: no real kittens are hurt in the process of asking and answering on Stackoverflow ;)